# Data duplication vs Encapsulating

Tags: c++, oop, data-structures, encapsulation

The problem that I face is how to combine encapsulating and optimal memory use.

I can't show you my code and therefore explain it on extensive (I hope) example.

Let's say we need to have a database of men. We want to know only 2 things about those people:

1. Age of the man (in hours from birth).
2. Name of the town he lives in.

The convenient and natural way to manage this data is to create an object, which correspond to a man and store them in an array:

```
class OMan1 {
  public:
    OMan( const int &age, const astring &t ): fAge(age), fTown(t) {}
    const int& age() const: { return fAge; }
    const astring& Town() const: { return fTown; }
    astring FullId() const: { return fTown+fAge; }
  private:
    int fAge;
    astring fTown;
}

OMan mans[N];
```

Here our OMans are self-containing object and everything fills nice.

Except of the fact that we clone names of the towns thousands of times, and waste memory and execution time this way.

An improvement we can do is to make independent array for town names and for each OMan store only age of the town and a pointer to towns array:

```
class OMan2 {
  // same functionality as for OMan1
    int fAge;
    int fTownId;
    astring* fTowns;
}
```

object is still self-contained, sizeof(int) + sizeof(void*) is much less then sizeof(astring), we win a lot. But still it is factor of 2-3 more than sizeof(fAge) and we repeat fTowns billions of times.

Memory optimisation is crucial for me, therefore what I do is keeping only fAge and fTownId and move such functionality as Town() and FullId() out of OMan class to some class OManDataBase:

```
class OMan3 {
  public:
    OMan( const int &age, const int &tid ): fAge(age), fTownId(tid) {}
    const int& age() const: { return fAge; }
    const int& TownId() const: { return fId; }
    // const astring& Town() const: { return fTown; }
    // astring FullId() const: { return fTown+fAge; }
  private:
    int fAge;
    int fTownId;
}

class OManDataBase {
  // constructor, destructor
    const int& age( const int& i) const: { return fMans[i].TownId()]; }
    const astring& Town( const int& i) const: { return fTown[fMans[i].TownId()]; }
    const astring& FullId( const int& i) const: { return Town(i)+age(i); }
  private:
    vector<OMan3> fMans;
    vector<astring> fTowns;
}
```

And OMan3 now is not self contained object. It doesn't know it's fullname, for instance. That means that if I need to do some data processing with one man I have to use whole OManDataBase instance:

```
OBillType47 NewBillType47( const OManDataBase &db, int i ) { ... }
```

instead of

```
OBillType47 NewBillType47( const OMan &m ) { ... }
```

encapsulation has been broken here and the code readabilty has been clearly decreased. (I put Type47 to emphasise that I can have a lot of functions, which works with Oman-S and can't include all of them into OManDataBase class).

I wonder **is there any other way(-s) to solve data duplication problem, keeping objects as self-containing as possible**?

Comment: Maybe you can create an array of OMan for each town, thus avoiding the need to store the id of the town...

Comment: @asalic, that's an idea. (But in my opinion I will complicate the code even more, since instead of 1D index @i I will need to use 2D index @{townI,i}, basically turning everything out)

Answer (score 0):

You can create a generic class like this:

```
enum class Towns {T1 = 0, T2 = 1...}
string TownsNames[] = {"T1", "T2"...}

class OManDB 
{
   map<Towns, OMan*> m;
// OR
   map<int, Towns> m; // map by Oman ID and town

public:
   void addOMan();
   Oman getOManById(int id);
   OMan *getOManArrByTown(Towns town);
   OMan getOManTown(int omanId);
   ...
}
```

The idea is to create a class to keep all records and do all operations for you, like a DB, where you don't have a dataset and a set of operations separated one from the other. Everything is in one place and you define operations as required.

This way, you can change the internal representation as you please, you can return an array of OMan you can basically do whatever you want without breaking exiting code. An user would know that he/she can obtain the OMan and doesn't need to know the exact method of storing the fields of it. You can store them in a single 64 bit field (for instance if the ID is only 32 bits and the town is an additional 32 bit field). It gives you freedom.

**UPDATE**

Okay, let's put aside encapsulation for the time being and let's deal with performance. Ideally for every bit of memory, you could store the ID and the town's ID in 2 different vectors and this will yield an important advantage if the size of the 2 fields is different and the compiler has to make a padding. Using 2 different arrays will give you the best option to store the data and avoid padding (of course you can use pack... but it is not recommendable)

Comment: I know and index of a man and I don't know an Id, which can be very different (suppose this is not Id, but age in days)

Comment: @klm123 I get it, but I showed you an example of how to hide the implementation from the user. If it is not public, you can represent and store an OMan however you want inside. Others will just retrieve the data as needed. It is like a database engine. You have a public interface to execute some queries but inside you can use whatever engine and representation you want. This is what I understand as encapsulation.

Comment: Then I don't get it probably. How do you call NewBillType47 function, which has to know Id(Age) and the Town name?

Comment: @klm123 I'm not sure I understand your question... NewBillType47 doesn't know the id of a man, but it knows the town, is that right? If so, you need the make a method to calculate the bill for a specific town...

Comment: About you update. Sorry if I wasn't clear, but the question about Data optimisation AND encapsulation, so I need something, which moves forward to full encapsulation and makes user code simplier.

Comment: NewBillType47 does not know a thing about a man, it knows only about billing, you need to put all information about the man in arguments of NewBillType47. And this information has to include Age and Town Name.

Comment: @klm123 Okay, then use the getOManBY<something> which will create an OMan and afterwards feed this object to the NewBillType47. It is slower, of course (you have to create a new object given some fields) but is the most memory friendly AND encapsulated.

Answer (score 0):

There is a special design pattern for such a problem: [Flyweight pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flyweight_pattern). Better use it.